# Best Practice For Syncing Added Removed Items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, collections, insert-update

**MVC Knockout.js Application**

I have an application that is written mostly using ASP.NET/MVC and KnockoutJs. Now, in many cases I have collections on my view-models that need to be synchronized to the sql database(ie. the added collection items need to be added and the removed collection items need to be removed in the database). I want to know what best practice I should use in my client, view-model, and server code. I have come across this requirement a few times and would like to isolate a single best way to handle it.

**One Way**

I could create list properties on client and server view-models for starting items, added items, and deleted items. My logic would be fairly simple on the server update;the starting items would be ignored;the added items would be inserted;and the deleted items would removed. The server code could simply loop through added and removed collection items but the client would be more complex dealing with the lists as well as having more verbose view-models.

**Another Way**

I could create a single list in my model and then upon update I could compare the original values creating added and removed lists based on the differences. This would make the server update logic a little more complex and the server/client view-models and client script less complex. The problem with this is it is dangerous if somehow no items are posted to the server everything will be wiped out.

**A Third Way**

Maybe I will need to have a list of dirty items with added or deleted flagged and do the appropriate action on the server when submitted. Then the question becomes should my list be part of the view-model on the server or just a collection as a secondary parameter to the update method.

```
public ActionResult Update(ViewModel viewModel, 
       List<ListTypeViewModel> dirtyItems) { ... }
```

I think this might work well. Although, I am having a little bit of a problem with the pattern of distinguishing whether the item was previously saved to the database from the new and removed items.  [I added a fiddle to support this on the client. I should be using this pattern.](http://jsfiddle.net/5ywbwr09/11/)

**Another Answer Maybe?**

If I am missing something obvious that would solve this problem please let me know. In this scenario ajax requests to update lists on the server immediately doesn't make sense since the user would want to rollback changes to the collections by clicking a cancel button.

Comment: I would simply have the server-side code for deleting, editing or adding an item always return the final list of items, which you can  then use to update your front-end. That way your front-end doesn't have to know about what just happened to your items collection back-end and rebuilds everything from scratch each time it receives any response from the server.

Comment: I could be wrong but I am not sure that this addresses the challenge. I don't have to care on the client what the server does. Although, it certainly needs to be taken care of on the client.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your problem then... basically from what I know in order to synchronize lists it's always better to create stuff "from scratch" than comparing things. For example, if the user deletes 2 items, edit 2 and finally add 2 more to the same collection and then only submits the change to the server, I find it more handy if possible to just delete the whole collection server side and rebuild it from the list sent by client. This is of course not always possible and in that case you may need to take action server-side each time the list is updated client-side...

Comment: I have references to those items in other places.

Comment: Then you're in one of the "not always possible" cases. But still I'm affraid I don't understand what your actual problem is as you seem to have a pretty good idea of what should be done...

Comment: It just seemed like I was doing it a couple different ways. I wanted to post this as a guide for others who have the same challenge while maybe getting some new ideas. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63270/discussion-between-jwize-and-bartdude).

Answer (score 0):

We've found trying manage this situation of CRUD operations on multiple entities a pain to manage and I would argue it's unnecessary, as the user can do a lot of work that could potentially get lost if something crashes or goes wrong.

We handle each CRUD operation separately, making it much simpler, and push out these changes using SignalR as they happen, so that all clients' knockout viewmodels are up-to-date and in sync.

Hope this helps.